# Which bits in the x87 tag word does FFREE ST(i) modify?

Tags: assembly, x86, x87

This example was written in NASM:

```
section .bss
    var28: resb  28


section .text
    _main:

        ; Initialize
            finit
            fldpi
        ; Read Tag Word
            fstenv [var28]
            mov    ax, [var28 + 8] ; move the Tag Word to ax
```

At this point ax = 0011 1111 1111 1111, which means ST7 = 00 (valid), and the rest is 11 (empty).

The rest of the code:

```
        ; FFREE ST(i)

            ffree ST7 ; Sets tag for ST(i) to empty.
            ; Read Tag Word
                fstenv [var28]
                mov    ax, [var28 + 8] ; move the Tag Word to ax
```

At this point ax = 0011 1111 1111 1111 too.
My question is, shouldn't be ax = **11**11 1111 1111 1111?

Comment: `FFREE` is only useful when combined with either `FDECSTP` or `FINCSTP`. The most common combination is `FFREE`+`FINCSTP`, which is equivalent to (and less efficient than) `FSTP`. I have yet to find a good reason to use `FFREE`.

Comment: @CodyGray I saw that post, it has nothing to do with my question. My question is more detailed and it's unfair to mark it as a duplicate for that post.

Comment: @CodyGray because people will go to the other question, considering it to be "original", though, it doesn't have as much details as this one.

Comment: @CodyGray: The old question didn't have a great answer (link + not much detail, and the notation used in the question didn't look very clear to me), so it worked better to mark it as a duplicate of this.  Both the question and answer here are well-written.

Comment: Agreed, @Peter. This is a better Q&A pair, so it makes sense to reverse the direction. Thanks for being so on top of the duplicate situation in this tag. One of these days, maybe I'll earn a gold tag badge in [assembly], too. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm not as active as I used to be.  I got burned out after seeing the same beginner questions multiple times after a couple years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *At this point ax = 0011 1111 1111 1111, which means ST7 = 00 (valid),
>   and the rest is 11 (empty)*.

**No**. The Tag Word refers to the registers (R7..R0), while `ST(i)` refers to the "top of the stack" (TOS) which can change.

The first `fldpi` sets the TOS (=`ST(0)`) to register R7 and loads PI into that register. A second `fld` would change the TOS to register R6 and fill that register. ST(0) would point then to the register of the second `fld`. `ffree st0` would free R6 (the second tag in the Tag Word) and set ST0 to R7. The Status Word contains a three-bit number with the register to which the TOS currently points.

In your example program, `fldpi` loads PI into `ST(0)` which points to R7. To empty R7 you have to use `ffree st0`.

Please take a look to Chapter 8 of the [Intel Manual Vol. 1](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) where it is discussed in detail.

Comment: Indeed, that what confused me. The instruction `FFREE ST(i)` uses TOS, to modify the TAG.